# Will Windows 8 take up less space than Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-8, virtualbox

I need to run a Windows virtual machine on my Mac, it doesn't really make much difference to me if I use 8 or 10, so would just like to use whichever will take up less space on my hard drive.

I found it a little hard to find a straight answer online... so if anyone could enlighten me that would be great.

If they're both the same then I mightaswell go with Windows 10

Comment: It really depends on a lot of things. Which edition of Windows. Which features you enable. Whether you install all of the updates. Whether you have a hibernate and page file... There is no "Windows 8 is smaller than Windows 10" sort of answer. Your choice should be based on how long the vendor/manufacturer will support the operating system for, and how long they'll issue security updates for. Windows 8.1 is already out of mainstream support.

Comment: @spikey_richie I see! thanks, probably best that I just go with W10 then

Comment: It would be my preferred option if I were in your position.

Comment: Windows 10 will bloat over time, like a few weeks, W8 on the other hand will not near as much, I have a W10 install I have done nothing with but updates, it is using 51gb space, also see this>>>>>>https://superuser.com/questions/987608/what-is-the-approximate-installation-size-of-a-clean-windows-10-upgrade-post