# How can i install windows 10 on a 35GB partition without any future problems?

Tags: linux, windows, disk-space, bloatware, auto-updates

I want to dual boot on Linux (as main OS) and on Windows.
How can I install Windows 10 so it can fit inside a ~35 GB partition? I won't use the Windows as the main OS, only for small programs that are currently supported only by Windows. 
Please provide me with a method to clean install a windows (older version also acceptable), without any bloatware and completely disable any form of windows update, because it takes a lot if space over time. 
 For example this user on [this post](https://superuser.com/a/1086637/1343942) says that windows took ~60GB of space after just a couple of days from
12GB clean install. This is why I need to disable auto-updates as soon as possible, or somehow tweak which "important" updates to be installed that are crucial for the system. I can change the allocated space for
the windows 10 partition, if it's not enough, but preferably not to exceed past 40 GB. I need the rest of space for my Linux distribution.
 
To summarize: My question is how to perform minimal Windows 10 installation (no bloatware) and to keep the initial clean install size without it later expanding.
Thanks

Comment: Will the small programs run under [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) on your Linux? If so, you wouldn't need to install Windows.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I am not sure, is there a list I can check the programs Wine supports? for example does it support CH341a programmer?

Comment: You can use a CH431a programmer directly: search on, e.g., Google for "ch341a linux".

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 can use 20GB or more to do a feature update. Updates will happen also.

The (more or less) average size for my 64-bit Windows virtual machines is 50 + GB.

So I would allow at least a 50 GB (possibly 60 GB) partition for Windows 10 if (as you say) to avoid future problems.

This assessment has been based on using Windows (and Linux) virtual machines over time.

If you must use Windows 10, consider getting additional disk space.

Comment: yes but my disk space is very limited and I can't afford 50-60 GB for windows, as I said I won't use it as my main OS, I will rarely use windows for small programs, only when needed, so I don't need the OS to grow in size. My question was how to maintain the initial installation size

Comment: Windows 10 will not keep the initial installation size - it always tends to grow until over time update cleanups shrink it. So you may wish to consider more disk space.

Comment: You also cannot realistically completely disable Windows Update on Windows 10.  There are tricks so you indefinitely delay the installation of an update.  However, eventually the build you are will be conceded "out of support" and there isn't a realistic way of avoiding the notification that will be displayed indicating that had indeed happen.  It might be easier to just use a virtual machine, you could realistically just throw away changes, and you simply refresh the Windows installation once a year.